# (sentence) Usage of 圏外

Tags: translation

人気アイドルにあやかって昨年上位を占めた「たくや」君はベストテン圏外。

I am confused by the usage of 圏外 in this sentence. My translation would be:

I was named after a popular idol, Takuya, who was at the top of popularity rankings, outside the top 10.

The fact that the idol was outside the top ten most popular idols is strange given that he already said "at the top". I would understand if there was a "but", as in "at the top, but not in the top 10". The way it is currently, it seems like "outside top ten" is somehow reinforcing the "at the top" part, which doesn't make sense logically.

Clarification: This sentence is part of an explanation about self introductions and にあやかって means 'named after' in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got to your translation.

Isn't everything before たくや君 a relative clause?

> Takuya-kun, who followed the example of popular idol(s) and ranked high last year, is outside the top ten.

Would this make sense in the context?

Edit:
Thanks Marasaiさん for pointing out that this is about baby names. So it translates like:

> Takuya, which ranked highly last year due to the popular idol (Takuya Kimura), is outside the top ten

The main point of the sentence is 「たくや」君はベストテン圏外 (Takuya is out of the top ten), but extra information about how it used to be in the top ten is added with the relative clause.

Comment: Okay, it could be translated that way, but what is the point of adding 'outside the top ten' into there? Isn't it confusing that 'is outside the top ten' is basically the main verb and predicate of the sentence despite being unrelated to the relative clause?

Comment: Isn't it all related though? He's out of the top ten now, but he was ranked highly last year. I think it's just using a relative clause to give relevant/interesting extra information.

Comment: Ash's translation is correct. The name "Takuya" was inside the top 10 baby names last year, but is outside the top 10 now. Many parents name their son after Takuya Kimura, who is a popular idol.

Comment: Ahh so it was about baby names! I should have guessed! Thanks marasaiさん :)